# Como guardar el color de un icono fontawesome en localstorage y obtener el color al refrescar pagina

Tags: local-storage

Hola buenos días actualmente lo realizaba de esta forma con jquery

```
$(".fa-camera").removeClass("yellow");
$(".fa-camera").addClass("white");
```

Alguien puede mostrame un ejemplo de como se realizaria con localstorage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para guardar información en localstorage desde js puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera

```
var someData ='Texto/variable/json a guardar'";
localStorage.setItem('myDataKey', someData);

// Get data
var data = localStorage.getItem('myDataKey');

// Remove data
localStorage.removeItem('myDatakey');
```

Puedes leer sobre ello [aqui](https://gomakethings.com/using-localstorage-to-save-user-data-with-vanilla-javascript/#:~:text=The%20localStorage%20API%20lets%20you,data%20value%20as%20the%20second.)

Para obtener la información despues de recargar se me ocurre que puedes hacer algo como

```
//check for Navigation Timing API support


  if (window.performance) {
      console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
  }
  if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
    console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
  } else {
    console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
  }
```

El codigo original lo obtienes de [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004978/check-if-page-gets-reloaded-or-refreshed-in-javascript)

Para unirlos puedes hacer algo como esto

```
if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
  var data = localStorage.getItem('color');

  console.info( "La variable recolectada es "+data );
} else {
  var someData = 'yellow';
  localStorage.setItem('color', someData);
  console.info("Variable almacenada");
}
```

De aqui ya nada mas necesitarias poner tu codigo con la variable